# How do I sample isampler3d in webgl2?

Tags: webgl2

two question. first off, how could I set a particular value in a 3d texture to 1, lets say the y coordinate of the element at index 1,1,1 in the following Int16Array so I could later read it. I think it'd go something like this:

```
var data = new Int16Array(size * size * size);
data.fill(0);

// ??? (somehow I'd set values of the data array at index 1,1,1 but I'm unsure how)
data ??? = 1;

gl.texImage3D(
  gl.TEXTURE_3D,
  0,
  gl.R16I,
  size,
  size,
  size,
  0,
  gl.RED_INTEGER,
  gl.SHORT,
  data);
```

secondly, later in my fragment shader, how could I grab that value using the GLSL texture function. I think it'd go something like this:

```
uniform isampler3d t_sampler;

...

ivec4 value = texture( t_sampler , vec3( 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 ) );
if( value.y == 1 ){
  // do some special stuff
}
```

any help would be appreciated. again I'm just trying to create my texture using a data array I create and then read that value in the frag shader.

fyi this code is running but failing to get to the "do some special stuff" part.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> // ??? (somehow I'd set values of the data array at index 1,1,1 but I'm unsure how)
>   data ??? = 1;

```
const width = ??
const height = ??
const depth = ??
const numChannels = 1; // 1 for RED, 2 for RG, 3 for RGB, 4 for RGBA
const sliceSize = width * height * numChannels;
const rowSize = width * numChannels;
const x = 1;
const y = 1;
const z = 1;

const offset = z * sliceSize + y * rowSize + x;
data[offset] = redValue;
```

If there are more channels, for example RGBA then

```
data[offset + 0] = redValue;
data[offset + 1] = greenValue;
data[offset + 2] = blueValue;
data[offset + 3] = alphaValue;
```

> how could I grab that value using the GLSL texture function

To get a specific value from a texture you can use `texelFetch` with pixel/texel coordinates.

```
uniform isampler3d t_sampler;

...
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int z = 1;
int mipLevel = 0;
ivec4 value = texelFetch(t_sampler, ivec3(x, y, z), mipLevel);
if( value.y == 1 ){
  // do some special stuff
}
```

Be sure to check the JavaScript console for errors. In your case you probably need to set filtering to `NEAREST` since you're not providing mips and since integer textures can not be filtered.

Comment: i did implement a solution that seemed to work shortly before this which I will try and share. I have yet to try this solution out but when I do I will update this post with my results.

Comment: by the way, is there a way to render to a 3d texture in GLSL to later read from the canvas in javascript? i saw other posts where you suggested using layers, but I was hoping there was a method for this similar to rendering to a 2d texture. perhaps I should start another post for this, but I think I already know the answer based on what I've read.